# What does selling on OpenSea do with a NFT, and how can I do it programatically?

Tags: nft, hardhat, polygon

Whenever you setup an existing NFT (minted outside of OpenSea) and use the "Sell" button, I assume the network will know it is up for sale. However, if you'd need to sell a bunch of NFTs at once, it will be a lot of wasted time. So how could I achieve the same thing programatically? I am on the Polygon network if that makes a difference. I am also using JavaScript with Hardhat

Short: How could I programatically sell a bunch of NFTs I own on OpenSea?

To clarify: The NFTs are already minted and can be found on OpenSea, I just need to sell them.

Answer (score 0):

You can create o loop with all the NFT address you would like to sell, you can use truffle CLI. There are other options.

Comment: Could you please add a link to documentation that might point me in the right direction, or add a code snippet? Thanks

Comment: https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/truffle-commands You can interact programmatically with any contract function through truffle console. Or you can use web3, check their documentation.

Comment: All you need is have the phrases of the ownerOF() the contract.

Comment: I have the keyphrase and own all NFTs, but I cannot find anything on Truffle for selling in a way that it shows up on OpenSea

Comment: Problably because you don't know how to call and send function on web3. You should start from the begining. You need to call allowBuy() in an array of address of your NFT contracts.